# Drupal 7: Remote site acting different from local site

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm noticing that my site is acting differently once I install Drupal 7 on a remote hosted site. The problem seems related to JavaScript, because neither (remote or local) site works when JavaScript is disabled in the browser.

I've been searching for ideas for several hours and am getting no where.

Behavior One: In Drupal 7 - when creating a content type, the "machine name" field is supposed to be auto-populated. This is not happening on my Remote site.

Behavior Two: The "Field Display" link in Display Suites does not work on the remote site. It appears on the Content Type - Manage Display page. The link appears but does not work.

Again - both of these behaviors appear to work correctly on my local Aquia Dev Desktop installation, but break when I install Drupal 7 on remote site.

NOTE: I'm assuming these behaviors are related, but I am not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: I finally resorted to setting up a new account with a new hosting service. Drupal 7 installed perfectly and all problems went away. Apparently, the problem was with the set-up or configuration of my old hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

This was likely related to the [Drupal7 mod_security issue](http://drupal.org/node/522646). If you still have access to the old host, you can confirm this by checking if the problem goes away after enabling "Aggregate JavaScript files." at Home >> Administration >> Configuration >> Performance (yourdomain.com/admin/config/development/performance). Basically, the server security setup is disabling access to a Drupal7 Javascript file with a specific name, and the missing file is killing certain Javascript features on the site. When you aggregate Javascript files, the offending name isn't used.